# Using regular expression to findi any character or no character?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to find all lines that contain a specific character for example "a". Using

```
^(.+)a
```

will only render the lines that don't start with the character "a", but contain them. Is there a way to express any characters or no characters?

Comment: I'm not sure your regex does what you think.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Perl, sed, Java, egrep...?

Comment: @Kirstoffer could you explain what "Is there a way to express any characters or no characters?" means exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the regex `a` should work in most line-by-line matchers.

See linepogl's answer for character-matching the whole line.

Comment: I think, he want to match the whole line, so this won't work. Needs clarification though.

Comment: @linepogl Yes, agreed, it really depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
^.*a.*$
```

The + means at least one, while the * means none or more.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is /a/. Its fairly rediculous to have the matching variable **actually** reproduce the contents of the entire source string.